# Design a table in SQL Database help (Beginner)

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Alright, so I have a table named `Users` that contains the following columns: `Username`,`Password`,`UserType`(determine whether it is a regular user or an admin).

Basically, I'm trying to simulate creating a kind of project with other users.

Therefore, I need to create a table named `Groups` who should be based on the `Users` table.

It should have the following data:
`Admin`,`Users`

The admin who created the project and the users who should be able to join the project.

How can I do that? Assuming that the column Users in the Groups table may have more than 1 user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Table Users:**

```
UserId, Name, Type
```

**Table Projects** [this table will store project information]

```
//AdminUserId = the admin user who created the Prject
ProjectId, Name, AdminUserId(FK)
```

**Table ProjectUsers**

```
// UserId = UserId of a user
ProjectId(FK), UserId(FK)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you add a unique numeric key to your users table: like `user_id`.

then create a new table for the groups:

```
group
----------
group_id
name
start_date
other_stuff
```

and finally, indicate which users are in the group

```
user_group
--------------
group_id
user_id
role <--- for instance admin etc.
start_date
end_date
possibly_other_stuff
```